# How to display loading gif on top of pop up?

Tags: java, gwt

I'm currently working an application built on GWT, where a page loads records in a pop-up window.

So there's a button on page, which is supposed to export the records to excel/PDF etc. However as there are a lot of records i.e. 100k or so, it takes a little time to export, so there's a loading gif which displays until report is downloaded.

Currently we're using DialogBox to display the pop-up :

```
DialogBox db = new DialogBox();
db.setWidget(displayListWidget);
db.setGlassEnabled(true);
db.setPopupPosition(1,1);
db.show();
```

Problem is the loading gif is displaying between the main page and the dialog box as above. Any ideas on how to display it on the DialogBox ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add the gif to the "displayListWidget" widget before calling db.setWidget(displayListWidget); and once the list is fully loaded you can trigger a fire event to hide the loading gif.